# React Native and native base edit data page

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm trying to create a page that where I can edit the 'tenant' data.

Here is my page:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import {
  Container, Header, Content, Card,
  CardItem, Text, Icon, Right,
  Left, Body, Title, Button }
from 'native-base';
import { Avatar } from 'react-native-elements';
import NavigationService from '../NavigationService';

class TenantDetails extends Component {
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header>
          <Left>
            <Button
              transparent
              onPress={() => NavigationService.navigate('Tenants')}
            >
              <Icon name='arrow-back' />
            </Button>
          </Left>
          <Body>
            <Title>My Name</Title>
          </Body>
          <Right />
        </Header>
        <Content>
          <View style={styles.userRow}>
            <View style={styles.userImage}>
              <Avatar
                rounded
                size="large"
                source={{
                  uri: 'https://myirent.com/rent/appImg/person-icon.png',
                }}
              />
            </View>
            <View>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>Jonh Test</Text>
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: 'gray',
                  fontSize: 16,
                }}
              >
                joinh@gmail.com{'\n'}xxx-xxx-xxxx
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <Card>
            <View style={styles.containerTextHeader}>
              <Text style={styles.infoTextHeader}>Tenant Details</Text>
            </View>
            <CardItem>
              <Icon active name="logo-googleplus" />
              <Text>First Name</Text>
              <Right>
                <Icon name="arrow-forward" />
              </Right>
            </CardItem>
          </Card>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scroll: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  userRow: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    paddingBottom: 8,
    paddingLeft: 15,
    paddingRight: 15,
    paddingTop: 6,
  },
  userImage: {
    marginRight: 12,
  },
  listItemContainer: {
    height: 55,
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: '#ECECEC',
  },
  containerTextHeader: {
    paddingTop: 20,
    paddingBottom: 12,
    backgroundColor: '#F4F5F4',
  },
  infoTextHeader: {
    fontSize: 16,
    marginLeft: 20,
    color: 'gray',
    fontWeight: '500',
  },
});

export default TenantDetails;
```

Thanks. I 'm having issue with the right arrow not align to the right (image below). Also, how can I change the  to have a label and value (Where I have First Name)? So when I click on it, I can open. modal to edit the value

Screen:
[image]

Comment: You mean you want to change the position of the arrow down on the right?

Answer (score 2):

here is part of your code. i add `Left` tag:

```js
<Card>
  <View style={styles.containerTextHeader}>
       <Text style={styles.infoTextHeader}>Tenant Details</Text>
 </View>
 <CardItem>
     <Left>
       <Icon active name="logo-googleplus" />
       <Text>First Name</Text>
     </Left>
     <Right>
       <Icon name="arrow-forward" />
     </Right>
 </CardItem>
</Card>
```

for modal problem, you can install `react-native-modal` by `npm install --save react-native-modal`.

wrap a button around `CardItem` that you need to onPress it. then call on onPress, a method that it changes your state of visibility for modal.
something such as this code:

```js
   <Modal
       style={{ margin: 0 }}
       isVisible={this.state.modalVisible}
   />
```

for changing of your field such as `name`, etc, use state of component

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. Is there a way to change the text style to have "First Name: Jonh Test". The text first name would be with a different style of "Jonh Test" just to separate the label and value?